# BinaryReader.ReadInt32 result unexpected compared to input file, why?

Tags: c#, binaryreader

I am puzzled with a particular `BinaryReader` operation.

When viewing a binary file with a hex editor (UltraEdit), the first four bytes are: `52 62 38 11`.

When iterating over the same file with a `BinaryReader`, if I call `ReadInt32()` first, I would expect the int value to be 1,382,168,593.

> `.ReadInt32()`: Reads a 4-byte signed integer from the current stream and advances the current position of the stream by four bytes.

Instead, I get 288,907,858.

Clearly I am missing something obvious... can anyone explain what is going on?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`BinaryReader` reads bytes in little-endian order.

Observe:

```
csharp> 0x52623811;  // What you expected it to read.
1382168593
csharp> 0x11386252;  // What it actually read.
288907858
```

If you need to specify the byte ordering of the data you are reading, I would suggest using [Mono.DataConvert](http://www.mono-project.com/Mono_DataConvert).  I've used it in several projects and it is incredibly useful, as well as MIT-licensed.  (It does use unsafe code for performance reasons, so you can't use it in untrusted contexts.)

See [the Wikipedia article on endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) for more info on the concept.

See [Microsoft's Reference Source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/system/io/binaryreader.cs.html) for details on the implementation of BinaryReader

Answer (score 3):

Intel architecture is [little endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness).  The last byte in the sequence has the highest value.  So 52 62 38 11 is equivalent to 0x11386252.